# Explicit wait best practice for most accurate results

Tags: c#, selenium

I have made a number of tests running with Selenium. I want to make my tests as strong as possible. I want to know should I use ElementToBeClickable or use elementExisits or both.

For example should I use

Method 1

```
public static WebDriverWait webDriverWait;
webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(excelSession, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(wordSession.FindElementByName("Create"))).Click();
```

Method 2

```
 By create = By.Name("Create");
                webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(create)).Click();
```

Method 3

```
        By create = By.Name("Create");
        webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(create)).Click();
        webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(excelSession.FindElement(create))).Click();
```

Comment: If the element is supposed to be clicked further down the lane, we should use `ElementToBeClickable` only. `ExpectedConditions` must be set as per your distinct actions only. Thanks

Comment: I always prefer using ElementIsClickable for most of my cases. In case for some reason the ElementIsClickable does not work (for disabled items), it is better to combine with some other checks and check for the availability of some other sibling elements.

Comment: I´m voting to close this question as opinion-based. We can´t know what *you* should do, we can only say what your API is *supposed to do* based on its documentation and that´s also what you read to answer your question. Of course there might be multiple ways to solve your problem, but which to chose is up to you allone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the element will be clicked at later point you can use following code

```
webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌BeClickable(wordSession.FindElementByName("Create"))).Click();
webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(create)).Click();
```

this won't work in few cases . It checks whether element is available in the DOM. It doesn't check whether element is visible in the UI.

You should be using **ElementIsVisible** instead, it is working fine.